# Printing an array in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

Just trying to do a tutorial from a few weeks ago and run into a bit of trouble.

I'm trying to retrieve all the data from an array inside of mysql. Here's my code so far, which kinda works.

```
include('db_conn.php'); //db connection


$query = "SELECT * FROM kit202_product";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{

    printf("%s %s %d %s\n", $row[0], $row[1],$row[2], $row[3]); 
}
```

The table is meant to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rlww.jpg)
[image]

While the code does work (it prints out every value), How do I organize it so it looks like that in the picture? 
I'm guessing I need to print into a table somehow?

Googling hasn't really gotten me anywhere. Only really shown be how to print one line of the array.

Comment: a table will replicate the one on your image. you should loop your rows inside the `<table>` tag with the `<tr> and <td>` tags.

Comment: have a gander over to the right, under **Related** >>>

Comment: All the answer is good here.But be careful how they close and open php tag.And also design your table with css to reach your desired design

Comment: *"Googling hasn't really gotten me anywhere."* - Google this "mysql html table". If that doesn't get you results, I don't know what will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in a table by looping your results inside the `<tr>s`

```
<?php 
include('db_conn.php'); //db connection


$query = "SELECT * FROM kit202_product";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
?>
<h1>Search Product Details</h1>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <?php 
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I tried doing echo "<li>" $row [1] "</li>" but that wasnt working.

Comment: i dont think `<li>` tags will work with tables. you could do it in `<ul>` or `<ol>` but that's a different thing from what your question is saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
include('db_conn.php'); //db connection


$query = "SELECT * FROM kit202_product";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Price</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th>";
echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
    {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Design your table with CSS

Comment: my bad, first time to answer here. Should have tried first on my editor.

Comment: if its just a string, use a single quote, like : echo '<table>';

Comment: @Clarence Improve your answer. `echo "<td>".$row[0], $row[1],$row[2], $row[3]."</td>"; ` This line may produce error and it will show one column only

Comment: @Shaiful Islam, Mr.Kevin Paul Kalis already made the correct answer. :)

Comment: You already answered and should make it correct.Many correct answer welcome at SO unless its duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('db_conn.php'); //db connection


$query = "SELECT * FROM kit202_product";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
?>
<TABLE BORDER="5"    WIDTH="50%"   CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
   <TR>
      <TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H3>Search Product Detail</H3>
      </TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>ID</TH>
      <TH>Name</TH>
      <TH>Price</TH>
      <TH>Description</TH>
   </TR>
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{
    echo "<TR ALIGN='CENTER'>
      <TD>$row[0]</TD>
      <TD>$row[1]</TD>
      <TD>$row[2]</TD>
      <TD>$row[3]</TD>
   </TR>"; 
}

?>

</TABLE>
```

Comment: I think you have to change this line `echo "<TR ALIGN="CENTER">` to `echo "<TR ALIGN='CENTER'>` other wise it will produce error.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Agreed; or `echo "<TR ALIGN=\"CENTER\">` is also acceptable, escaping the double quotes.